# Print ArrayList element without square bracket and comma

Tags: java, arraylist

I wanted to print all element of an ArrayList just like an array, without creating array from ArrayList.
Actually,

```
ArrayList a=new ArrayList();
a.add(1);
a.add(2);
a.add(3);
System.out.println(a);
```

here output:[1,2,3]

I wanted to print these element like as : 1 2 3

How can I do that?Is there any method in ArrayList?

Comment: You need to override the `toString()` of the `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that. But first, you will have to specify which type the List will use. I also recommend you to use List as datatype and not ArrayList. In your example it would be

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
```

To print it, you can either call

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a.toArray()));
```

but I would recommend to do it with a for-loop or a for-each-loop. Just like that

```
// for-loop: This will iterate through the list by index
for(int i=0; i < a.size(); i++){
    System.out.print(a.get(i));
}
System.out.println();

// for-each: This will iterate through the list by Iterator
for(Integer val : a){
    System.out.print(val + " ");
}
System.out.println();
```

I hope I could help you

Comment: Thaks to your comment .

Comment: for loop and for each loop work . But in your first process System.out .println(a.toArray());--->give an exception like   : [Ljava.lang.Object;@15db9742

Comment: Oh, that's not an Exception, it's data from the Array. it should be `Arrays.toString(a.toArray())` I'll update it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use Lambda Expressions:

```
a.forEach(System.out::println);
a.forEach( elem -> System.out.print(elem + " "));
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to obtain your result is to use [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) class in this way:

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
a.add(1);
a.add(2);
a.add(3);

StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" ");
for (Integer elem : a) {
    sj.add(elem.toString());
}

String spaceSeparatedNumbers = sj.toString();
System.out.println(spaceSeparatedNumbers); //<-- it will print 1, 2, 3
```

An alternative way to obtain the same result is a `Stream` using `Collectors.joining` in this way:

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
a.add(1);
a.add(2);
a.add(3);

String spaceSeparatedNumbers = a.stream()
         .map(i -> i.toString())
         .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

System.out.println(spaceSeparatedNumbers); //<-- it will print 1, 2, 3
```